# Mongo query of array

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongo document that contains (among other things) the following information:

```
{
    "_id": "1519649521772A",
    "setTitle": "Los Animales",
    "vocab": [{
        "english": "the dog",
        "foreign": "el perro"
    },{
        "english": "the cat",
        "foreign": "el gato"
    }]
}
```

Now, I'm trying to do some queries to find this document. The following query returns this document as expect:

```
db.cardsets.find({setTitle:"Los Animales"})
```

But this one returns nothing:

```
db.cardsets.find({vocab:{foreign:"el gato"}})
```

Could someone tell me what's wrong with my query? I've tried several versions with and without quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `$elemMatch` operator:

```
db.cardsets.find({vocab: {$elemMatch: {foreign:'el gato'}})
```

It is used to match elements inside an array. [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)